# Alternative to web worker on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, web-worker

The Android AOSP browser and WebView pre-4.4 doesn't support web worker. I'm porting a small web app to Android using WebView, and in this web app there is a web worker used to do some heavy tasks in the background and update the UI with the progress.

I looked around and see that WebView class has the `evaluateJavascript()` function, which can be used to evaluate Javascript asynchronously. However, this method can only accept a callback to call at the end of the script execution, so I cannot use it to post message to my web app's main UI thread to update the task progress.

Is there an alternative to web worker on Android, with the ability to post message back and forth to the  main thread?

Answer (score 0):

run this          http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

you can see Web Workers do run on Android - send your users to those browsers

[image]